# Error in getting feature dimension on Kaldi for Voice recognition?

Tags: voice-recognition, kaldi

I have done 'Kaldi for dummies' example for Voice recognition. But I am getting the following error. Anyone knows how to fix it?

[error message showing while running Kaldi for dummies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP02S.png)

Comment: Could you post your error as text and not as an image?

Comment: http://textuploader.com/dgb4r